# Copy app URL from Google Play

Tags: google-play-store, keyboard-shortcuts, editing

In Google Play, how do I copy the URL of an app I'm browsing so that I can paste it into a post or on a word document or notepad using my Android device? In a web browser it's easy to do this, but what about other apps that have corresponding URLs or other URIs?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you have [Google Drive](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.docs) installed on your device then you can use the 'Copy to clipboard' option within the share menu.

If you scroll down past the reviews you should see a 'Share' button:

[image: Share button]

After clicking this you will be shown the share menu which contains a 'Copy to clipboard' option:

[image: Copy to clipboard]

Clicking this will copy the URL for the app to your clipboard, allowing you to paste this into another app.

Comment: This requires the Google Drive app to be installed.

Comment: @SuperThomasLab thanks, i wasn't aware of that. Added that info to my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can click in "Share" link and then tap unto Copy to clipboard.

[image: Share and then Copy to Clipboard]

Comment: the difference is that it just don't explain to the user the dependency on Google drive.

Comment: You might not know this, but the "copy to clipboard" is a feature of the Google Drive app.